# dask conditional select - iloc missing

Tags: python, dask

How can I implement

```
df.loc[df.some_string_column == '', 'some_string_column'] = np.nan
```

in dask?
Das does not seem to support the usage of bloc /loc indexers. The error I get is

```
TypeError: '_LocIndexer' object does not support item assignment
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking, in dask you will have to use assignments to create new data-frames, rather than mutating existing data-frames; although the syntax is similar, a new computation graph is being created. In your case, this could look something like:

```
df['some_string_column'] = df.some_string_column.map(
    lambda x: x if x else np.nan))
```

or

```
df['some_string_column'] = df.some_string_column.where(
    df.some_string_column != '', np.nan)
```

Comment: To be more explicit, you can forgo the syntax convenience in favour of the older `df2 = df.assign(some_string_column=...)`, which is more explicit.